# Properties are always null @ ConfigurationProperties when using @ TestPropertySource

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, dependency-injection

Properties are always null `@ConfigurationProperties` when using `@TestPropertySource`

Configuration file *application.yml*:

```
integration:
  some:
    configuration:
      userInfo: testUser
```

Configuration class

```
@Component
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="integration.some.configuration")
public class SomeProperties {    
    private String userInfo;
}
```

Service class:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SomeProperties.class)
public class SomeServiceImpl {
        private final SomeProperties someProperties;
    public String get() {
            return someProperties.getUserInfo();
        }
}
```

Test fixture:

```
@SpringJUnitConfig({
        SomeServiceImpl.class,
        SomeProperties.class})
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
        "integration.some.configuration.userInfo=someUser"
})
class SomeServiceImplTest {
    @Autowired
    SomeServiceImpl someServiceImpl;

    @Test
    void someTest() {
       String user = someServiceImpl.get();
       ....
    } 
}
```

In above test, the injected user is always `null`.

Comment: Could you please post the exact configuration and type declaration? I am pretty sure you are not using the `integration.some.configuration` property and naming really matters in such context.

Comment: I can't, I'm not allowed to do it

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the autowiring

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableConfigurationProperties(SomeProperties.class)
public class SomeServiceImpl {

    @Autowired // <--------
    private final SomeProperties someProperties;

    public String get() {
            return someProperties.getUserInfo();
        }
}
```

Also since you have `@Component` placed on SomeProperties you can remove the
`@EnableConfigurationProperties(SomeProperties.class)`

Comment: Not sure this could be the issue as he has not shared the whole sources and he may be using constructor or setter injection.

Answer (score 0):

Check the spelling of the keys in application.properties vs what you have defined in the class SomeProperties

Example that can cause null.

```
integration:
  some:
    configuration:
      userInfo: testUser
```

Here, as an example, I spelled userInfo wrong. Wrote userInformation. which will give null.

```
@Component
@Data
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="integration.some.configuration")
public class SomeProperties {    
    private String userInformation;
}
```